# Audio Device busy from service on systemd vs command line

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, alsa

A specific issue for me is using snapclient on a raspberry pi.

I have snapclient running alongside a voice assistant.
If I start snapclient using command line

```
sudo snapclient -h 192.168.x.xxx -s 3 --player=alsa &
```

then my voice assistant can output to the same audio output and i hear both streams.

If I use the systemd startup

```
sudo systemctl start snapclient.service
```

then the voice assistant audio is blocked with device/resource busy.

using htop (there is most likely a better way to do this) I can see the user and full args list when its started via systemd and I replicate this exactly when I run from the command line to no avail.

Could someone please advise what I need to learn about to be able to get this to run the same from systemd or if it would be better to do this via rc.local possibly? Any and all recommendations for how to learn this are welcome.

I am sure it is probably a permissions issue but I don't know how to look for the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using alsa to play audio from a service on ubuntu/orangepi "Can't open audio hw:0: Device or resource busy".

I was able to resolve it by adding "Requires=dbus.service" and "Environment=DISPLAY=:0" to the unit config.

Here's my working unit config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Buttons sound app
Requires=dbus.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/orangepi/runSoundServer.sh
User=orangepi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```